# Can someone look over this implementation of the equals method I wrote for my Circularly Linked List?

Tags: java, list, data-structures

Here is my implementation of an equals method. Can someone check it out for me to let me know if it'll work or how I can improve it?

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == null) return false;
    if (getClass() != o.getClass())
        return false;
    CircularlyLinkedList other = (CircularlyLinkedList) o;
    if (size != other.size)
        return false;
    if (tail != other.tail)
        return false;
    Node walkA = tail.getNext();
    Node walkB = other.tail.getNext();
    Node sentinel = tail;
    while (walkA != sentinel) {
        if (!(walkA.getElement().equals(walkB.getElement())))
            return false;
        walkA = walkA.getNext();
        walkB = walkB.getNext();
    }
    return true;
}
```

But now will I be calling the equals method for this class instead of the Object.equals method?

Comment: Keep in mind if `tail` are separate `Node` objects your reference comparison (`!=`/`==`) will fail. You'd want to compare the contents of the nodes. On top of that you should be re-assigning the `walkA`/`walkB` variables. Lastly, look into `Object#equals` for use on the actual contained objects in your collection

Comment: Why don't you write a program to test it?  (Incidentally, I suspect this method won't terminate, for some lists).

Comment: Optimal time to learn about JUnit :)

Comment: btw, you never reassign `walkA` or `walkB` to actually be the next nodes

Comment: so i should use Object.equals instead of !=, okay that makes sense. And yes @cricket_007 i see that now thanks

Comment: @Rogue I think the `!=` comparison with `sentinel` is OK, because the idea is to run around the ring in a circle, and return to the starting node.  It's the `!=` comparison between the elements that seems wrong to me, although that really depends on OP's expectation of how this should work.  The biggest issue though is the failure to re-assign `walkA` and `walkB` in the loop.

Comment: check my edit please

Comment: Seriously, you should write a program to test this.  Don't cloudsource your software testing to the Stack Overflow community - we're far too fallible.

Comment: There is still a problem here `if (tail != other.tail)`: should compare elements instead of `Node` references.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I believe I got it.

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != o.getClass())
        return false;
    CircularlyLinkedList other = (CircularlyLinkedList) o;
    if (size != other.size)
        return false;
    if (tail.equals(other.tail))
        return false;
    Node walkA = tail.getNext();
    Node walkB = other.tail.getNext();
    int sizeA = size;
    while (sizeA > 0) {
        if (!walkA.getElement().equals(walkB.getElement()))
            return false;
        walkA = walkA.getNext();
        walkB = walkB.getNext();
        sizeA--;
    }
    return true;
}
```

My test program worked fine.

```
public class TestLinkedLists {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DoublyLinkedList<String> double1 = new DoublyLinkedList<>();
    DoublyLinkedList<String> double2 = new DoublyLinkedList<>();
    DoublyLinkedList<String> double3 = new DoublyLinkedList<>();
    DoublyLinkedList<String> double4 = new DoublyLinkedList<>();
    CircularlyLinkedList<String> circ1 = new CircularlyLinkedList<>();
    CircularlyLinkedList<String> circ2 = new CircularlyLinkedList<>();
    CircularlyLinkedList<String> circ3 = new CircularlyLinkedList<>();
    CircularlyLinkedList<String> circ4 = new CircularlyLinkedList<>();

    double1.addFirst("asdf");
    double1.addFirst("ghjk");
    double2.addFirst("asdf");
    double2.addFirst("ghjk");

    double3.addFirst("asdf");
    double3.addFirst("asdf");
    double4.addFirst("ghjk");
    double4.addFirst("ghjk");

    circ1.addFirst("asdf");
    circ1.addFirst("ghjk");
    circ2.addFirst("asdf");
    circ2.addFirst("ghjk");

    circ3.addFirst("asdf");
    circ3.addFirst("asdf");
    circ4.addFirst("ghjk");
    circ4.addFirst("ghjk");

    System.out.println(double1.equals(double2));
    System.out.println(double3.equals(double4));
    System.out.println(circ1.equals(circ2));
    System.out.println(circ3.equals(circ4));
}
```

}

Comment: Dang why the -1?